# Cambiar el valor de (data-percentage) en la clase circlechart, con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estoy intentando resolver el tema de `data-percentage`, he intentado modificar el valor con `Jquery` pero no tengo resultado, y error tampoco.

Dejo mi código para que se visualice mi función. Qué pudiese estar ocurriendo.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="circlechart" id="porcentajes" data-percentage="0"></div>
</div>
<script type=text/javascript>
  $('#porcentajes').attr('data-percentage', 100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edito mi respuesta porque he cometido un grave error:**

En JQuery [el método](https://api.jquery.com/data/) `data()` solo permite obtener los valores de los atributos `data-`

Para modificar los valores de los atributos `data-` se usa, como bien lo haces en tu pregunta, el método `attr()`

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

Ahora bien, respondiendo a porque no funcionario tu código, quiero pensar que es porque no hay nada que desencadene el proceso `$('#porcentajes').data('percentage', 100);`

Lo que podrías hacer es poner esa linea de código dentro de la función `$( document ).ready()` [que lo que hace es detectar cuando la pagina esta lista para ejecutar código javascript](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Te dejo el código con las recomendaciones aplicadas.

*Hice que el `div` fuera visible solo para fines prácticos, si inspeccionas el elemento te darás cuenta que ya tiene el valor especificado.

```css
#porcentajes{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <div class="circlechart" id="porcentajes" data-percentage="0"></div>
</div>

<script type=text/javascript>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#porcentajes').attr('data-percentage', 100);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Lo he intentado, coloque la linea con el data, pero el porcentaje sigue sin actualizar.

Comment: @Chemox hice unas modificaciones a mi respuesta, puedes revisarla y ver si ahora te funciona.